# providing an image for button_to in rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there any way to change the provide an image for the button in the following code

```
<%= button_to 'Edit treatment', edit_treatment_path(@treatment), :type => "submit", :class => "style3", :method => "get" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to submit a form by image click (assuming that since your type is "submit") you can use

```
image_submit_tag("your_image.png", :class => "style3")
```

If you meant a standard button you can use

```
link_to image_tag("your_image.png"), edit_treatment_path(@treatment), :class => "style3"
```